# Perform UI changes before performing AFNetwork request

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, afnetworking

I have a `UIButton` in a login view controller that when pressed, fetches the value from a `UITextField` and performs a POST request to a server, via `AFNetwork`. I wanna hide the text field and display a `UIActivityIndicatorView` right after the button is pressed, so that the user sees that something is happening.

The problem is, the request is asynchronous and happens before I can even update the UI. So please help me find a way to achieve the desired behavior

```
pwdTextField.hidden = true

// Start the activity indicator
activityIndicator.startAnimating()    

// How can I make this happen before the actual request?    

let token = pwdTextField.text.trim()
let requestURL = "https://myapi.com/authenticate/"

manager.POST(requestURL, parameters: [ "code" : token ], success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
       NSLog("Success! Response is \(responseObject.description)")
}, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
       println("Failure! Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       self.displayLoginAttempErrorAlert()
}).waitUntilFinished()
```

Comment: Just add this 2 lines before the request URL. Isn't this working.

Comment: Try performing the UI update in main thread by `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{  });` and make sure you are initialised `activityIndicator` and it is not `hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove waitUntilFinished().. It blocks execution of the current thread until the operation object finish its task..

```
manager.POST(requestURL, parameters: [ "code" : token ], success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
   NSLog("Success! Response is \(responseObject.description)")
 }, 
 failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
   println("Failure! Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   self.displayLoginAttempErrorAlert()
 })
```

Comment: very well noticed, @Kalpesh. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below method which starts and stops the activity indicator on main thread in a single method, also provides you to execute your code asynchronously as well -

```
- (void) buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    // hide your text field or do any code just before performing request
    // start the activity indicator (you are now on the main queue)
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // do your background code here
        // perform request here
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // stop the activity indicator (you are now on the main queue again)  
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    });
}
```

**Note**: The above sample code is just skeleton, you can populate/ customize it as per your requirements.